# Why do I get error "Name or Service not known" when encrypting Azure VM?

Tags: azure, encryption, virtual-machine

I am trying to encrypt a VM in Azure using the following code

```
    $keyVault = Get-AzureRmKeyVault –VaultName “azkeyvaultWestUS” -ResourceGroupName “azkeyvault”;
    $diskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl = $keyVault.VaultUri;
    $keyVaultResourceId = $keyVault.ResourceId;
    $keyEncryptionKeyUrl = (Get-AzureKeyVaultKey –VaultName “azkeyvaultWestUS” –Name “azpavdiskencryption”).Key.kid;
```

But when I tried to run it, I got the message

> Get-AzKeyVaultKey:  Name or Service not known

After the instruction ending in .Key.kid

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it separately and it should bye key.id

```
$Key = Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName "azkeyvaultWestUS" -Name 'azpavdiskencryption'

#get uri
$keyEncryptionKeyUrl = $Key.key.kid
```

Comment: I made the change and got the same error message, but now it is  after the line that starts $Key=.  It is still the same error message "Get-AzKeyVaultKey: Name or service not known"

Comment: then you are not passing the correct parameters, double check on azure portal whether values are correct

Comment: Encrypting the VM is part of an online class.  How can I determine correct values for the parameters?